# Programmatically set poster frame of .MOV in ios

Tags: ios, avfoundation, quicktime, qtkit

on Mac OS, `QtKit` allows me to load in a quicktime movie and set the poster frame.

that framework isn't ported to ios.

is there an alternative way to do this?

I'm writing the movie using `AVAssetWriter`, so I'd love to set this before saving, but I'd be fine loading it in afterwards and manipulate it later

Comment: I think the Mac version you are talking about is the `QTMoviePosterTimeAttribute` key, which I believe is QT specific metadata representing a time offset, probably estimated to the closest keyframe.  It might be settable in the `AVAsset` metadata somehow, but I don't see any equivalent const on the iOS side.  It seems that most implementations of web players – including for videos on Apple's own website – get their poster image separately from an external image.  Try making a video on the mac side and spitting out the metadata from the loaded AVAsset on the other side to see what you get.